# cPickle: UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'A'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a pickle file which upon unpickling throws an `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'A'.` exception. The exception gets thrown regardless of whether I try to analyse it on the Ubuntu 14.04 machine on which the file was generated or on my Windows machine. It contains 26 data points and the exception gets thrown after data point 11. I suspect I must have somehow accidentally edited the file though I don't know when or how. I know there are several other discussions on this sort of error but so far I haven't found a post yet telling me if and how I could go about recovering the values after the faulty entry (I suspect one of the values is just irretrievably lost). Is there any way I could skip it and carry on unpickling the next one? Can one e.g. unpickle in the reverse direction, i.e. last element first? Then I could work backwards till I hit the faulty entry and thus get the other values. (I could regenerate the data but it would take a day or two so I would rather avoid having to do that if I can.)

This is the code for pickling:

```
with open('hist_vs_years2.pkl', 'ab') as hist_pkl:
        pickle.dump(hist, hist_pkl, -1)
```

And this is the code for unpickling:

```
hist_vs_samples2 = []
more_values = True

with open('hist_vs_years2.pkl', 'rb') as hist_vs_samples_pkl:
    while more_values == True:
        try:
            hist_vs_samples2.append(pickle.load(hist_vs_samples_pkl))
        except EOFError:
            more_values = False
```

I should add that I am using cPickle. If I try to unpickle using pickle I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)

KeyError: 'A'
```

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the pickle file. Your storing code suggests you have just one object, in which case you have to fix the load key as there is no way to load pickled objects partially. If you actually store several objects (not a *list* of several objects), you can delete the broken one. If you want to do this on your own, the `pickle.py` source lists the load keys, which also explain the format.

Comment: My apologies, the pickling code sits in a larger loop. They are separate objects indeed. How would I identify the relevant section of the pickle file do you know? I will try and find an explanation online in the meantime.

Comment: I'm afraid pickling files are not meant to be user-readable. You'll have to dig through it yourself; to make it simpler, print the index of all objects that worked, then search from there onwards.

Comment: Going through my file it seems like entries begin with `€]q(cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct` and end with `tbe.` So I deleted the twelth entry. Unpickling it now seems to interestingly load all 27 entires precisely as expected so I am not sure what went wrong there (for some reason an extra, broken entry must have been inserted) but thank you very much for your help! If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll happilly accept it.

Comment: don't use pickle, it's very sensible to get corrupted (e.g. UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.) use alternatives instead. pickle not strong enough. if corrupted the only solution is to erase it and create a new one (i.e: not recoverable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When storing multiple objects (by repeated `dump`, not from containers) Pickle will store objects sequentially in pickle files, so if an object is broken it can be removed without corrupting the others.

In principle, the pickle format is pseudo-documented in `pickle.py`. For most cases, the opcodes at the beginning of the module are sufficient to piece together what is happening. Basically, pickle files are an instruction on how to build objects.

How readable a pickle file is depends on its pickle format - 0 is doable, everything above is **difficult**. Whether you can fix or must delete depends entirely on this. What's consistent is that each individual pickle ends with a dot (`.`). For example, `b'Va\np0\n.'` and `b'\x80\x04\x95\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x01a\x94.'` both are the character '"a"', but in protocol 0 and 4.

The simplest form of recovery is to count the number of objects you can load:

```
with open('/my/pickle.pkl', 'rb') as pkl_source:
    idx = 1
    while True:
        pickle.load(pkl_source)
        print(idx)
        idx += 1
```

Then open the pickle file, skip as many objects and remove everything up to the next `.`.